# The connection properties object must be of type SqlConnectionProperties or OleDBSqlConnectionPropertiies

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022

I seem to keep getting this error when trying to create a connection between visual studio 2022 and Sql. (seems to work in VS 2019 when tested on my machine).

From the update Wizard when I click new connection:

[image]

when I leave everything as default Microsoft Sql Server as the data source and ".net framework data provider for SQL server" as the data provider.

[image]

when I hit continue I get the following error:

[image]

the connection properties then seems to load but when i hit OK i get another message:

[image]

I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried updating to the lastest version of visual Studio as well as checking the machine.config for both the 64 bit and 32 bit instances of .net on my machine. As some others have suggested, but to no avail.

in both cases my machine.config looked like so:

```html
  <system.data>
           <DbProviderFactories/>
    </system.data>
```

I've tried removing the "DbProviderFactories" tag in both and restarted my machine but that didn't seem to make much difference.

```html
<system.data>  </system.data>
```

I'm not sure if its normal for this to be blank. Perhaps I'm missing some components. but checking the Visual studio installer i seem to already have all the data components downloaded and installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this. For anyone who also runs into this issue. I had to completely uninstall visual studio 2022 and reinstall .net framework 4.81 runtime followed by the SDK. After doing this I reinstalled Visual studio 2022 and my machine. Upon loading my solution and trying to add the connection I no longer get the message and am able to connect to my DB.

Comment: I'm having the same exact situation now, though I'm using EntityFramework Powertools with EFCore 7. Very annoying.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: I tried to reinstall both Visual Studio 2022 and .net framework by .net framework repair tool also uncheck and checked the .net framework in control panle >> programs and features >> turn windows features on and off and restarted my device. Nothing has changed and still getting the same error.
It's giving me a headache after working on it for about a complete day.

Comment: Hey @Matin check what version of .net framework your application requires and then download it from the .net site and install it via the exe you've just downloaded then restart. In my case it was .net 4.81
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481

If i recall correctly using the repair tool didn't help me either.

Comment: I tried the same steps but that didn't help.  Kindly suggest the exact steps along with the link to download the.net framework and SDK you mentioned above.

Comment: The only difference is I am not getting the second error, it just gets back to the "Choose Data Source" screen again. And OS: Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to install the package that is missing in the visual studio installer. After installing it, open your solution, and try again.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which packet is missing? What would they install to fix this issue?